# Cannot extract hours from mongodb date array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am sucessfully getting data in date format into webservice based on NodeJS+MongoDB. But I cant extract hours from it.
This is date looks in MongoDB:

[image: MongoDB]

I try to either split the array elements or apply Date.getHours method using forEach loop.
The problem is that when I just console log elements in forEach loop, I can see my comment I wrote in only the last element in array which I suppose means that forEach loop does not go through all the elements in the array.

This is the code:

```
user.TrainingPlan[req.params.object].time.forEach(function(item, index, array)
{

console.log(user.TrainingPlan[req.params.object].time.toString() + ' xxx');

});
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

Comment: *"I try to either split the array elements or apply Date.getHours"* - I see no such code here. Don't just talk about it. Show us.

Comment: you are not using the current "item" inside the forEach loop, you're printing out the entire "time" object in every iteration

Comment: You are not printing item of time, but printing time as per item times i.e.(3 times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by splitting date format instead. Here is the code:

```
 var timestamps = user.TrainingPlan[req.params.object].time;

                var tlength = timestamps.length;

                for(var i=0; i<tlength;i++){

                    var dateInfo = timestamps[i].toLocaleString()
                    var splittedData = dateInfo.split(' ');

                    var yearMonthDay = splittedData[0];
                    var data2 = yearMonthDay.split('-');
                    var year = data2[0];
                    ...

}
```